# Where should i call a method from database for removing item for listView?

Tags: android, database, listview

i need help with removing item from listView and database. I saw some questions similar to mine here asked, but i couldn't get done anything from their answers because i'm new in this and still catching all this.

By the way, listView is in fragment and here is some part of code from fragment activity:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_moj_spisak, container, false);
    final EditText unos = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final Button dodajDugme = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final DodajProizvodListAdapter dpl = new DodajProizvodListAdapter(getActivity());

    dpl.addAll(DBHelper.getConnection(getActivity()).getAllProizvodi());

    lv.setAdapter(dpl);

    dodajDugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DBHelper.getConnection(getActivity())
            .saveProizvod(unos.getText().toString());

            ArrayList<String> allProizvodi = DBHelper.getConnection(getActivity()).getAllProizvodi();

            dpl.addAll(allProizvodi);

            unos.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Proizvod je dodat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    return view;


}   

}
```

And here is some part of code from adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dodaj_proizvod_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setTag(position);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
            lv.remove(index.intValue());
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    final CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ctv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ctv.isChecked())

                ctv.setChecked(false);

            else

                ctv.setChecked(true);


        }
    });
    ctv.setText(lv.get(position));
    return convertView;
}

}
```

and here's the code from dataBase:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "proizvod.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final String TABLE_PROIZVODI = "proizvodi";

    private final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private final String COLUMN_PROIZVOD = "proizvodi";

private static DBHelper dbh;

private DBHelper(Activity activity) {
    super(activity, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public static synchronized DBHelper getConnection(Activity activity) {
    if (dbh == null)
        dbh = new DBHelper(activity);
    return dbh;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String upitZaPravljanjeBaze = 
            "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PROIZVODI+"("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+COLUMN_PROIZVOD+" TEXT);";       
    db.execSQL(upitZaPravljanjeBaze);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE" + "TABLE_PROIZVODI");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getAllProizvodi() {
    ArrayList<String> toRet = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROIZVODI, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(c.isAfterLast() == false) {
        toRet.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PROIZVOD)));
        c.moveToNext();

    }

    return toRet;
}

public long saveProizvod(String proizvod) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_PROIZVOD, proizvod);
    return db.insert(TABLE_PROIZVODI, null, cv);
}

public void deleteByName(String name) {          
       SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
       db.delete(TABLE_PROIZVODI, COLUMN_ID +"=?", new String [] { name });
       db.close();
    }
```

Comment: you can use list view setOnItemLongClickListener method you can write your code in this method else also you can use setOnItemClickListener what you can do is you can generate a dialog asking user confirmation again and write your code on OK button.

Comment: Hello Sumeet, i have used setOnClickListener on my imageView which is ''X'' buton for deleting items from listView. How would i implement there method which will delete items from listView and database? Thank you.

Comment: in that case use your custom adapter getview method, i will provide you one link hope you will get what you want "http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html"

Comment: Web Page in maintenance you gave me :(

Comment: i have provided you below with the code from that link

Answer (score 0):

> **Activity.java**

```
    ListView userList;
 UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
 ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  /**
   * add item in arraylist
   */
  userArray.add(new User("Mumer", "Spain", "Spain"));
  userArray.add(new User("Jon", "EW", "USA"));
  userArray.add(new User("Broom", "Span", "SWA"));
  userArray.add(new User("Lee", "Aus", "AUS"));
  userArray.add(new User("Jon", "EW", "USA"));
  userArray.add(new User("Broom", "Span", "SWA"));
  userArray.add(new User("Lee", "Aus", "AUS"));
  /**
   * set item into adapter
   */
  userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row,
    userArray);
  userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
  userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
  /**
   * get on item click listener
   */
  userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
     final int position, long id) {
    Log.i("List View Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
      "List View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
   }
  });

 }
```

> CustomAdapter.java

```
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
 Context context;
 int layoutResourceId;
 ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

 public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
   ArrayList<User> data) {
  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
  this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
  this.context = context;
  this.data = data;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  UserHolder holder = null;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
   holder = new UserHolder();
   holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   holder.textAddress = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
   holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
  }
  User user = data.get(position);
  holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
  holder.textAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
  holder.textLocation.setText(user.getLocation());
  holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Edit button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  return row;

 }

 static class UserHolder {
  TextView textName;
  TextView textAddress;
  TextView textLocation;
  Button btnEdit;
  Button btnDelete;
 }
```